# Are EnumMaps in Java perfect hash maps?

Tags: java, hash, enums, perfect-hash

If the list of hash keys for a hash function is known and immutable, it is possible to generate a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). A [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) in Java is a list of known and immutable elements. Therefor it should be possible to implement the [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) as a perfect hash. Is this currently (1.7) done in Java?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the implementation of `EnumMap`? What do you think is not 'perfect' about it?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No I tried to find it in the API documentation.

Comment: The sourcecode is included in the JDK.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes the compiled classes are there, too. ;-)

Comment: @ceving - and have you still not looked at them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  `EnumMap` doesn't use hashing.  It uses the `enum` ordinal values as indexes into an array of the value type.

Reference:

- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/EnumMap.java#EnumMap.getKeyUniverse%28java.lang.Class%29.  (If this link breaks, Google for "java.util.EnumMap source".)

Comment: You could argue it does use hashing and that hash is the (unique) enum `ordinal()` ;)

Comment: Since when was a simply indexed array a hash table?  It would only be a hash table if there was a non-trivial hash function that turned the `enum` value into a hash value.

Comment: I'm not entirely serious, but in the context of a 'perfect hash function' as mentioned in the question and the fact that you can look at `ordinal()` as being that perfect hash function, then it is not a big leap to consider the indexed array access as a hash table.

Comment: And FWIW, `Enum.hashcode()` does not return the ordinal.  It just calls `super.hashcode()`.  Yes, I suppose that you could say that a perfect hash table does behave like a (typically sparse) array *after* you have hashed the key.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. Could that mean that theoretically the `Enum.hashcode()` could have collisions, while `Enum.ordinal()` cannot?

Answer (score 3):

The link you name "EnumHashMap" actually points to a class named "EnumMap", there are no hashes involved there:

> Enum maps are represented internally as arrays. This representation is extremely compact and efficient

For the sake of argument, one could argue that the mapping of enum - values to integer (as index into the abovementioned array) IS a hash function and yes, it is perfect, as there are no colissions.

Answer (score 3):

`EnumMap` is not any kind of `HashMap` that would use hashing internally to `put` and `get` data. It uses `Array` to store the `<K, V>` pair where `K` is an `Enumeration constant` and uses `ordinal value` (the position of the `Enumeration constant` in the declaring `Enum`, is known as ordinal value) internally to `put` or `get` data.  [Enum.ordinal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method is used for getting `ordinal value` of a given `Enumeration constant`.

In other words, `EnumMap` does not use hashing but ordinal values of the `Enumeration constant` as the index to `put` or `get` the `<K, V>` pair in its internal `array`.

You can check the source code of [EnumMap.put](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/EnumMap.java#EnumMap.put%28java.lang.Enum%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) for being over sure!

Comment: Yes, I see... :P And I also edited my answer. You can see it.

Answer (score 1):

EnumMap are not hash based, they are based on arrays

private transient K[] keyUniverse;
... 
private transient Object[] vals;